# Замена старых ссылок контроллера на новые

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, рефакторинг

Делаю свой pet проект для ознакомления с asp.net core mvc. Первоначально был контроллер `User` который отвечал за работу с пользователем (регистрация, авторизация, смена пароля и выход) и был метод `Login` который отвечал за вход. В один момент мне захотелось изменить имя контроллера с `User` на `Account`, а имя метода с `Login` на `Sigin` и пошла замена ссылок везде где только можно. В общем всплыли у меня 2 проблемы:

1. Как быть если необходимо поменять имя контроллера или метода, то тогда искать во всём проекте старые имена и менять их на новые (View, код, класс `Startup` при настройке `CookieAuthenticationOptions`)
2. Как быть, если проект разросся до >=10 контроллеров и в каждом из них >=5 методов `HttpGet` и в голове всех их уже не упомнишь и нужно один из них вызвать.

Вот как я решил свои проблемы

```
    public static class LinksConstants
        {
            public static class Account
            {
                public const String Controller = "Account";
                public const String SignUpActionName = "SignUp";
                public const String SignInActionName = "SignIn";
                public const String ChangePasswordActionName = "ChangePassword";
                public const String SignOutActionName = "SignOut";
                public static readonly String SignUpLink;
                public static readonly String SignInLink;
                public static readonly String ChangePasswordLink;
                public static readonly String SignOutLink;

                static Account()
                {
                    String mask = "/{0}/{1}";

                    SignUpLink = String.Format(mask , Controller , SignUpActionName);
                    SignInLink = String.Format(mask , Controller , SignInActionName);
                    ChangePasswordLink = String.Format(mask , Controller , ChangePasswordActionName);
                    SignOutLink = String.Format(mask , Controller , SignOutActionName);
                }
            }
        }

        public class AccountController : Controller
        {
            [HttpGet, AllowAnonymous, ActionName(LinksConstants.Account.SignInActionName)]
            public async Task<IActionResult> SignInView([FromServices] SignInManager signInManager ,
                                                        [FromQuery] String returnUrl = null)
            {
                //do work
            }
        }
    <div class="clearfix">
        <a class="float-right"  asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" asp-controller=@LinksConstants.Account.Controller asp-action=@LinksConstants.Account.SignUpActionName>Create account</a>
    </div>
```

Как у Вас, в реальных проектах решаются такие проблемы?

Модель

```
public sealed class SignInViewModel
    {
        #region Fields
        public static readonly SignInViewModel Empty;

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public String Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [Remote(action: LinksConstants.RemoteValidation.ValidationPasswordActionName , controller: LinksConstants.RemoteValidation.Controller)]
        public String Password { get; set; }


        [ScaffoldColumn(false), ValidateNever]
        public String ReturnUrl { get; set; }
        #endregion Fields

        static SignInViewModel()
        {
            Empty = new SignInViewModel()
            {
                ReturnUrl = "/"
            };
        }

        public async Task ValidationOnServer(ModelStateDictionary modelState , UserManager userManager)
        {
            UserEntity user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Email);
            if (user is null || !await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user , Password))
            {
                String message = "Invalid email or password";
                modelState.TryAddModelError(nameof(Email) , message);
                modelState.TryAddModelError(nameof(Password) , message);
            }
        }

    }
```

View

```
@using WebContacts.Models.Account;

@model SignInViewModel
@section Scripts
{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="account" method="post" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">
        <div class="container py-0 ">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center ">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
                    <div class="card shadow-2-strong" style="border-radius: 1rem;">
                        <div class="card-body p-5 text-center">

                            <h3 class="mb-5">Sign in</h3>

                            <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                                <input class="form-control form-control-lg" asp-for="@Model.Email" />
                                <label class="form-label" asp-for="@Model.Email"></label>
                                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="@Model.Email"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                                <input class="form-control form-control-lg" asp-for="@Model.Password" />
                                <label class="form-label" asp-for="@Model.Password"></label>
                                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="@Model.Password"></span>
                            </div>

                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <a class="float-right"  asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" asp-controller=@LinksConstants.Account.Controller asp-action=@LinksConstants.Account.SignUpActionName>Create account</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы в студии можете нажать на нужное вам имя в классе (хоть неймспейс, без разницы), затем нажать `Ctrl + R + R`, подсветится текст выбранный определенным цветом (в зависимости от цветовой темы VS) и вы можете начать печатать любое нужное вам имя, все ссылки автоматически будут изменены под измененное имя

Comment: А по поводу 2-го пункта, у нас в проекте есть js код который в рантайме создает вызов ajax на нужный API контроллер и его метод, вы можете это сделать руками не в рантайме и тогда даже в консоли браузера можно будет обратиться к методу js который вызовет метод контроллера. Лучше это конечно делать в рантайме

Comment: На счет именований классов - сначала думайте "а нужно ли?", затем "а что нужно-то?", после выписываете в блокнотик что нужно (не название методов, а на человеческом языке условно "зарегаться на сайте") и "а не много ли?", если нет - думаете над именем и проблем с переименовыванием не будет :)

Comment: @Aarnihauta > Вы в студии можете нажать на нужное вам имя в классе (хоть неймспейс,
 без разницы), затем нажать Ctrl + R + R. 

Допустим, воспользовался я комбинацией и `UserController` изменил на `AccountController`, но это не поменяло ссылки в View так как там константы `asp-controller=@"User"`

Касательно предварительного планирования - согласен.

Comment: Конечно не поменяло, там ведь какие-нибудь стринг константы, ну тут уж только ручками менять) На счет вьюшек - делайте ViewModel внутри Page чтобы не париться с именованием контроллера

Comment: @Aarnihauta  > На счет вьюшек - делайте ViewModel внутри Page чтобы не париться с именованием контроллера. 

Это как? У меня есть свои ViewModel, но как это поможет?

Comment: Покажите код вашего View (включая ViewModel)

Comment: @Aarnihauta обновил

Comment: Ну норм, если проблема в поиске имен и их ренейминге - используйте `Ctrl + F` с выбором "В текущем решении", а студия покажет весь возможный текст ссылающийся на имя. Так же окошко выпадающее в `Ctrl + F` позволяет отредактировать искомый текст на какой-то новый (там потыкайте посмотрите, поймете)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137617/discussion-between-user-and-aarnihauta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кратко: вам нужна автоматическая замена имён классов-контроллеров и имён методов в них.

Идеально для этого подходит [nameof](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof).
Единственное, что нужно сделать, принять именование контроллеров без суффикса, т. е. в виде `Account`, а не `AccountController`.
Соглашения о наименованиях позволяют это делать: [What is a Controller?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions?view=aspnetcore-6.0#what-is-a-controller).

В tag helper пишем

```
<a asp-controller="@nameof(Account)" asp-action="@nameof(Account.SignInView)">Create account</a>
```

и всё прекрасно работает.
После чего можно без проблем делать переименования методов и классов.

---

Осознал: это решает не все проблемы. Остаётся вопрос автоматического переименования View и ViewModel.

С вьюхами наверняка можно что-то намутить с помощью `IViewLocationExpander` interface.
В реальных проектах я пока не встречал такого, но в книге Modern API Design with ASP.NET Core 2, Fanie Reynders, есть пример, как задать собственные соглашения по именованию контроллеров с помощью `IApplicationModelConvention`.
По аналогии можно и собственные соглашения по именованию View сделать.

Остаются ViewModel. Тут наверняка на помощь могут прийти Source Generators.
Вот только боюсь, если всё это реализовать, вас потом проклянут те, кто будут поддерживать проект.

---

Ещё бы я посоветовал посмотреть в сторону Vertical Slice Architecture. Отказаться от традиционного размещения: контроллеры в папку Controllers, вьюхи в папку Views, модели в папку Models.
Вместо этого группировать их по назначению: в папке Account располагаются вместе контроллер, модель, вьюха и прочее, что относится к аккаунту. Тогда переименование станет намного проще: не нужно метаться по разным папкам, вспоминая, где ещё что-то забыто.

Однако, и это полностью не решит проблему, т. к. иногда бывает необходимо сделать редирект из одного контроллера в другой. Тогда при изменении имени в одной папке *придётся* менять его и в другой. Но всё же это редкость.

Comment: @User - перенёс ответ из чата.